# plugin com.apple.share.Mail.compose invalidated (Cocoa-NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)

Tags: swift, cocoa, xcode7.3

In my Cocoa application, I have a button for sending an e-mail:

```
@IBAction func emailFeedBack(sender: NSButton) {
    sender.enabled = false

    //mail composition
    let subject = "[Feedback]"
    let body = "\n\n\nFeedback From my app:\n"
    let service = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)
    service?.delegate = self
    service?.recipients = ["myMail@mail.com"]
    service?.subject = subject
    let shareItems = [body] as NSArray
    service?.performWithItems(shareItems as [AnyObject])

    //activate the button after 1 sec
    let delayTime = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 1)
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayTime),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    sender.enabled = true
    })
}
```

It works and launches Mail app as expected. However, I get this message on the debug console:

> plugin com.apple.share.Mail.compose invalidated

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have same issue for obj-c project. I think it's not important, as everything works.